# Looking for Source for explanation in Chafetz Chaim

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, parashas-kedoshim, acharonim

R' Moshe Sherer brings an interesting explanation from the Chafetz Chaim:
The reason for the Torah's double expression of my Shabbos's in ויקרא יט:ג - ואת שבתותי תשמורו is to teach us that our Shabbos observance is incomplete so long as there are others around us who are not Shabbos observant.

שבתותי teaches us that to properly observe שבת. I need to observe my own and do my utmost to ensure that others are keeping theirs.
בשתי עינים p48 and http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_50144_6.pdf

I have not managed to find this explanation in any of the Chafetz Chaim's writings (though have come across a different explanations in Shem Olam Chap. 4).

Comment: Ibn Ezra (*Vayikra* 19:3, *v'es shabsosai tishmoru*) suggests that the plural form indicates that you should also encourage others to observe Shabbos, but I think he is referring to the plural form of "*tishmoru*": ואמר תיראו לשון רבים, כי חייבים הרואים ללמדו ולהכריחו, וכן בשמירת שבת.

Comment: The Ohr Hachaim brings another Peshat where he relates that the Ibn Ezra found out through a miracle that somebody was trying to convince others that day precedes night on Shabbos.
He disproved him by saying that mother precedes father in that Pasuk as mother represents night and father represents day.. This demonstrates that night precedes day.

Comment: @Zvi There is a vast number of different kinds of *diyukim* made and explanations given surrounding the text here. Since you bring it up, though, you are talking about the Ibn Ezra's critique of the Rashbam discussed in [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5469) (see also [this article](http://www.vbm-torah.org/parsha.64/29acharei-kedoshim.htm) and the addendum to [this article](http://thetorah.com/can-torah-contradict-halacha/) that translates the Ibn Ezra's comments about his dream).

Comment: Not sure if this counts as an answer, but I found this explanation in the name of the Choftez Chaim in two other places: a collections of sayings on the parsha called Imrei Chein (1990), pg 243, and a collection of statements about shabbos called Yom Shekulo Shabbos, pg 18-19. Does being quoted in 3 different places make it a chazaka that it's actually been said (orally, perhaps) by the Chofetz Chaim?

Comment: @ Matt, Perhaps, but his source may be R' Sherer, so we're back to square one.

Comment: @Zvi The Imrei Chein was published first but you're right in theory that they could all be getting it from the same place

Comment: @ Matt. You're references are certainly the best so far - post them as an answer, and I'll award you the bounty ;)

Answer (score 2):

Shout out to Matt for the sources.

In [Yom Shekulo Shabbos page 18-19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53057&st=%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A5&pgnum=18), and Imrei Chein page 243 (I think [this is it](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51842&st=&pgnum=243&hilite=), but don't see the quote) it has this quoted in the name of the Chafetz Chaim.